# How can I use and extract kerning values from TrueType fonts to correctly show glyphs using C++ library?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, truetype, kerning

I need to extract Kerning values of TrueType Fonts using C++ library

Comment: We don't generally recommend libraries here, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Is it possible to Extract kern values using C++? I could find all the results in python

Comment: Of course. I found a library on the first hit of a simple Google search.